# Need help dividing the ratio of elements in a Python list

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am working on a problem where I have been asked to a) output Fibonacci numbers in a sequence based on user input, as I have done below, and b) divide and print the ratio of the two most recent terms.

```
fixed_start = [0, 1]          

def fib(fixed_start, n):      
    if n == 0:
        return fixed_start    
    else:
        fixed_start.append(fixed_start[-1] + fixed_start[-2])  
        return fib(fixed_start, n -1)      

numb = int(input('How many terms: '))

fibonacci_list = fib(fixed_start, numb)

print(fibonacci_list[:-1])
```

I would like for my output to look something like the below:

```
"How many terms:" 3

1 1
the ratio is 1.0
1 2
the ratio is 2.0
2 3
the ratio is 1.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for ratio of the last 2 items in the list? If yes, this should work.

```
print(fibonacci_list[-2:])
print(float(fibonacci_list[-1]/fibonacci_list[-2]))
```

Or, if you are looking for ratio between every 2 numbers (except 0 & 1 right at the start), the below code should do the trick

```
for x,y in zip(fibonacci_list[1:],fibonacci_list[2:]):
    print(x,y)
    print('the ratio is ' + str(round((y/x),3)))
```

**output** is something like below for a fibonacci list of 15 terms

```
1 1
the ratio is 1.0
1 2
the ratio is 2.0
2 3
the ratio is 1.5
3 5
the ratio is 1.667
5 8
the ratio is 1.6
8 13
the ratio is 1.625
13 21
the ratio is 1.615
21 34
the ratio is 1.619
34 55
the ratio is 1.618
55 89
the ratio is 1.618
89 144
the ratio is 1.618
144 233
the ratio is 1.618
233 377
the ratio is 1.618
377 610
the ratio is 1.618
610 987
the ratio is 1.618
```

Comment: If the answer helped you. Consider up-voting & accepting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already solved the part one of generating the Fibonacci series in the form of a list, you can access the last two elements (most recent) from it and take their ratio. Python allows us to access the elements of the list from backwards using the negative indexing

```
def fibonacci_ratio(fibonacci_list):
    last_element = fibonacci_list[-1]
    second_last_element = fibonacci_list[-2]
    ratio = last_element//second_last_element
    return ratio
```

The double // in python will ensure floating point division.
Hope this helps!

Comment: `//` guarantees an *integer* result…